# undefined method `symbolize_keys!' for "/reie":String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gravatar

I 'm working on a tumbnail that's gonna contain all the friend gravatar with a link to each friend profile .I got every thing working till i add this part. , `other_user_page_path(friend.username)` the error is

```
undefined method `symbolize_keys!' for "/reie":String
```

here is the entire code

```
<% current_user.friends_of.each do |friend| %>
       <%=  link_to image_tag (friend.gravatar_url(:size => 30)) , other_user_page_path(friend.username)%>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: You pass a string where hash is expected. It's hard to tell more using information you provided

Comment: Yes, "image_tag " is looked at as a method without arguments in 1.9.x (atleast in 1.9.3) , but works like a method with arguments in 1.8.7. I found this in a code and removing the space after the image_tag works well.

Answer (score 1):

The error is here

```
  <%=  link_to image_tag (friend.gravatar_url(:size => 30))
 , other_user_page_path(friend.username)%>
```

remove the space after image_tag. Change it to like this.

```
 <%=  link_to image_tag(friend.gravatar_url(:size => 30))
 , other_user_page_path(friend.username)%>
```

This should fix your problem.

Comment: this explanation feels silly, but it remains valid; the two spaces are what throws the engine off.

Answer (score 0):

```
<% current_user.friends_of.each do |friend| %>
       <%= link_to(image_tag (friend.gravatar_url(:size => 30)) , other_user_page_path(friend.username)) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Don't know why but i got it working with this link_to `<%= image_tag(friend.gravatar_url(:size => 30)) , other_user_page_path(friend.username) %>` is rails space sensitive ?

Comment: Not from what I can tell, but it's best to have only one space after <%=. It also is easier to use link_to() with parenthesis when you're calling a method inside both of its parameters, from my experience anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<% current_user.friends_of.each do |friend| %>
   <%=  link_to other_user_page_path(friend.username) do %>
     <%= image_tag(friend.gravatar_url(:size => 30)) %>
   <% end %>   
<% end %>
```

Comment: Don't know why but i got it working with this `<%= link_to  image_tag(friend.gravatar_url(:size => 30)) , other_user_page_path(friend.username) %>` is rails space sensitive ?

Comment: It is not about spaces and not about rails. It is all about ruby and parenthesis. Ruby allows omitting parenthesis in method calls. However it is always a good idea not to omit them if you evaluate some expression to get some argument value. If you still omit parenthesis you should be aware of the ruby parsing rules: you need to understand what expression will become an argument of which method. By adding parenthesis you just make your code a bit cleaner.